# Flutter accessing private values

Tags: java, dart, flutter

I'm dealing with floating action bars and since in Kanban class my _show method is private I can't access it. I've tried converting to static but then my database releated methods caused problems. I don't know what to do any advice ?

Here the class I want to access

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:entrecor/Util/KanbanScreen.dart' ;

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {

....

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Welcome'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
              child: Text('Logout',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17.0, color: Colors.white)),
              onPressed: () => _signOut(context)),
        ],
      ),
      body: Tabs(),
      floatingActionButton:Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: <Widget>[
            FloatingActionButton(
              heroTag: 'FAB1',
                    onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NotePage()),
                );
              },
              tooltip: 'Add Note',
              child: Icon(Icons.note_add),
            ),
            FloatingActionButton(
              heroTag: 'FAB2',
              child: Icon(Icons.share,color: Colors.white,),
              onPressed: _showFormDialog,
            ),
          ],
        )
    );
  }
}
```

And this is the class I want to access from

```
import 'package:entrecor/Model/todoitem.dart';
import 'package:entrecor/Util/database_client.dart';
import 'package:entrecor/Util/dateformatter.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class KanbanScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _KanbanScreenState createState() => _KanbanScreenState();
}

class _KanbanScreenState extends State<KanbanScreen> {
  final TextEditingController _textEditingController =
      new TextEditingController();

  var db = new DatabaseHelper();

  final List<TODOItem> _itemList = <TODOItem>[];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _readToDoList();
  }

  void _handleSubmitted(String text) async {
    _textEditingController.clear();

    TODOItem todoItem = new TODOItem(text, dateFormatted());
    int savedItemId = await db.saveItem(todoItem);

    TODOItem addedItem = await db.getItem(savedItemId);

    setState(() {
      _itemList.insert(0, addedItem);
    });

    print("Item saved id: $savedItemId");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Flexible(
            child: ListView.builder(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              reverse: false,
              itemCount: _itemList.length,
              itemBuilder: (__, int index) {
                return Card(
                  color: Colors.black12,
                  child: new ListTile(
                    title: _itemList[index],
                    onLongPress: () => _updateItem(_itemList[index], index),
                    trailing: new Listener(
                      key: new Key(_itemList[index].itemName),
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.remove_circle,
                        color: Colors.redAccent,
                      ),
                      onPointerDown: (pointerEvent) =>
                          _deleteToDo(_itemList[index].id, index),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
          new Divider(
            height: 1.0,
          )
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        tooltip: "Add Item",
        child: ListTile(
          title: Icon(Icons.add),                       //Basiicaly ı want 
                                                           this in home class
        ),
        onPressed: _showFormDialog,
      ),
    );
  }

  void _showFormDialog() {
    var alert = new AlertDialog(
      content: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Expanded(
            child: new TextField(
              controller: _textEditingController,
              autofocus: true,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: "Item",
                  hintText: "eg. Just Do It",
                  icon: Icon(Icons.note_add)),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
      actions: <Widget>[
        new FlatButton(
          onPressed: () {
            _handleSubmitted(_textEditingController.text);
            _textEditingController.clear();
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          child: Text("Save"),
        ),
        FlatButton(
          onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
          child: Text("Cancel"),
        )
      ],
    );


  void _handleSubmittedUpdate(int index, TODOItem item) {
    setState(() {
      _itemList.removeWhere((element) {
        _itemList[index].itemName == item.itemName;
      });
    });
  }
...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do your method non-private - rename `_show` to `show`.

If you methods, fields or class names start with `_`-symbol - they're private

Comment: chancing _showFormDialog to showFormDialog sisnt worked.

Comment: Show how exactly do you try to call this method. I you do it without creating instance of your class - of course you have to make this method static

Comment: In here FloatingActionButton(
              heroTag: 'FAB2',
              child: Icon(Icons.share,color: Colors.white,),
              onPressed: // __showFormDialog,
            ),

Comment: In this case you're trying to call private methon in same class. Change your question - show how exactly do you want to call this methon in another class

Comment: Do you want to call same action on two different screens?

Comment: No right now there is a fab in Kanban Screen I dont want it here. I want to call this in home class under the second fab (first one is add) so when I try to call it as _showFormDialog cuz it is private.

Comment: So, why don't you put this method inside `HomePage`?

Comment: I meant - why don't you create the same method inside `HomePage`?

Comment: When I do that it also gives error beause inside this function a lot of stuff is connected

Comment: I see it. Why can't you copy ol necessary methods and fields in home?

Comment: Basically it will be a mixture of whole database class and home class There should be a more proper way.

Comment: There is, but I still can't understand what exactly do you want. You can create one `DbProvider` class and encapsulate necessary logic inside. You can create abstract class with needed method and extend from it. So there can be many ways